# MVC Razor @helper function unable to recurse properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, recursion

My model for my view contains an object that I need to iterate through and display some HTML for each of its properties (I'm making a way for users to compile razor messages with the @Model syntax). The properties are only displayed if they have the necessary attribute (*this part works*). However, the recursion does not seem to be occurring as expected.

When debugging and stepping into the recursive call, I see that the fields that should be recursed into *are*, but the call function is skipped over. That is, following the pointer to show the current executing line of code, it the pointer skips directly from the open to close bracket (with the correct parameters of the recursive call, mind you) without ever executing anything between.

```
@helper OutputProperties(Type type, string path)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var info in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var attrib = info.IsDefined(typeof(RazorAccessibleAttribute), false);
            if (attrib)
            {
                <li>
                    @if (@IsTypePrimitive(info.PropertyType))
                    {
                        <a data-value="@(path + "." + info.Name)">@info.Name</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a data-value="@(path + "." + info.Name)" href="#">@info.Name</a>
                    }
                </li>
                if (!@IsTypePrimitive(info.PropertyType))
                {
                    OutputProperties(info.PropertyType, path + "." + info.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    </ul>
}
```

It's also worth nothing that I tested a simple recursive function, and this too failed to work.

```
@helper recurseTest() 
{  
    recurseTest();
}
```

Again, there is no stackoverflow (heh) error as the recursion never actually happens. I tested my function with both @ and without in front of the call (not sure what the difference is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding "@" in front of the method within should take care of it ...

```
@OutputProperties(info.PropertyType, path + "." + info.Name);
```

update :
Complete tested code with minor changes to the original

```
@helper OutputProperties(Type type, string path)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var info in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var attrib = true;//info.IsDefined(typeof(RazorAccessibleAttribute), false);
            if (attrib)
            {
                <li>
                    @if (info.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        <a data-value="@(path + "." + info.Name)">@info.Name</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a data-value="@(path + "." + info.Name)" href="#">@info.Name</a>
                    }
                </li>
                    if (!@info.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        @OutputProperties(info.PropertyType, path + "." + info.Name);
                    }
            }
        }
    </ul>
}

<p>
    @OutputProperties(typeof(MvcTestBench.Models.ManagerUser), "Model")
</p>
```

Comment: Hey Sam, I did try that but to no avail. That was actually how I originally wrote it, and what you see is the result of hours of trying everything.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue by omitting the "@" which made the view engine not to attempt to render the output of the helper function. try the sample in the update ... just to see if that is any help ...

Comment: No dice. The only thing I changed from yours was to check again for the attributes (some objects that I have contain a lot of inner objects, which contain even more..need to not include these), but the end result was the same sort of skipping over the entire recursive call.

Comment: That is very strange ... from my end even this code does the recursion fine @helper recurseTest()
{
    @recurseTest();
}  .... "@recuseTest()" being the code I modified from your post ...

Comment: ...the @OutputProperties needed to be inside the <li> tags. Simple solution to a simple problem, ^^;